# Безопасный интерпретатор пользовательской логики (кода)

Tags: php, песочница, sandbox

Доброго времени суток!

Периодически сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда в админке сайта вместо пачки стандартных настроек "на все случаи жизни" (в формате галочек, селектов и текстовых полей) гораздо проще (и для пользователя приемлемо) оставить место для ввода небольшого куска кода, которым он сможет реализовать любую логику.

Ну, например, типовая ситуация - универсальная система управления способами доставки для интернет-магазина. Есть сущность "служба доставки", экземплярами которой являются различные службы доставки, и каждая со своей логикой тарификации... У одних стоимость доставки считается как "минимальная стоимость + доп.вес х цена доп.веса", у других - фикс, но зависит от города, у третьих - нелинейная сетка типа "0..1кг, 1..5кг, 5..25кг и т.п.", у четвертых - система наценок за определенный тип товара, и т.п. И при подключении очередного хитрого доставщика, приходится лезть в код и добавлять поддержку новых понятий, создавать для них особые настройки, и т.п.

Понятно, что "по феншую" надо вывести универсальный набор параметров, подходящий для любой логики, но во-первых, это неоправданное усложнение, а во-вторых - всеравно найдется очередной хитрый болт с левой резьбой, который вылетит за рамки, поэтому порой проще создать создать набор настроек для стандартной логики расчета, а для всего "за рамками" оставить одно тектовое поле, где подкованный менеджер сможет просто ввести кусок кода, и реализовать любую хитрую логику.

**Задача** - обеспечить возможность настройки любой новой логики для нового перевозчика "из админки", без вмешательства в код. НО! при этом соблюсти безопасность при выполнении этого кода, и ограничить его (кода) возможности исключительно приемом входных параметров (данные о заказе, товарах, доставке и т.п.) и возвратом результата в стандартном виде (ну, например, одного числа - итоговой стоимости доставки).

**Собственно, вопрос**: наверняка, есть какие-то готовые инструменты для подобной задачи? понятно, что крайний случай - пилить свой велосипед, но вопрос именно про существующие инструменты или полуфабрикаты.

Какие варианты приходят на ум:

- php eval - укажу здесь просто для полноты списка, т.к. сразу отметается по соображениям безопасности (хотя, может есть способы запускать eval в песочнице и ограничить его влияние на внешнюю среду?
- smarty - уже лучше, если закрутить все гайки безопасности; правда, требование "вернуть только число при рендеренге" и запрет на php-вызовы сильно вредят читабельности, но по крайней мере, это уже вариант...

**А на что еще стоит посмотреть?**

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: хотелось бы получить фидбек

Answer (score 3):

Подобные ситуации с дополнительной логикой нередко встречаются, например в игровой индустрии.

Для решения довольно часто используют визуальные блок-схемы. Каждый блок отвечает за какое-либо действие, одни из них выполняют математические и логические вычисления, другие отправку уведомлений работникам и т.п. 
Эти блоки ваш менеджер выстраивает в схему и запускает её в дело — наглядно и удобно.

Если же всё настолько сложно, что блок-схемой не обойтись, можно задействовать встраиваемый язык, например `Lua`.
Это полноценный язык (похож на js) с возможностью расширения. Из него неумелый пользователь не сможет удалить все данные из БД, если только вы сами не предоставили ему такой инструмент. Касательно PHP, поддержка Lua [присутствует](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.lua.php).

Comment: да, спасибо, Lua - вполне себе вариант (и не потому, что "все сложно", а скорее потому, что гораздо быстрее воткнуть в проект, чем пилить собственный графический язык.

Comment: кстати, сейчас я еще смотрю в сторону Symfony Expression Language, который тоже можно подключить (вроде как теперь он умеет жить самостоятельно, отдельно от фреймворка). Тоже вполне вариант (для менее замороченной логики, которую можно впихнуть в одно выражение, пусть даже длинное и разветвленное).

Comment: а для блок-схем известны какие-то готовые инструменты для php ?

Comment: В php достаточно написать несколько функций, которые будут реализовывать логику блоков. А для построения схем есть множество инструментов на js. Например [JsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/)

Comment: прикольная штука... правда, 4 строчки кода превращаются в полный экран, за что я и не люблю блок-схемы -))

Answer (score 0):

Самый безопасный вариант: написать собственный полноценный интерпретатор DSL-языка. Самая пугающая начинающего часть -- написание синтакс.парсера, делается средствами типа lex/yacc, для Python пользуюсь PLY, для PHP тоже должен быть готовый генератор парсеров типа: https://github.com/jakubkulhan/pacc

Безопасность обеспечивается тем, что весь потенциально опасный трэшкод изолируется внутри структур данных виртуальной машины интерпретатора, единственный потенциально опасный случай -- переполнение динамических структур, предусмотрите механизм аккуратного отстрела клиента.